# Why should lifetime parameters be declared before type parameters?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I was trying out a simple function when I got this compiler error. What is the actual reason behind this? In my case (following code), writing the type parameter before the lifetime parameter has no effect. Shouldn't the compiler know better?

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn random_func<T : Debug, 'a>(parameter : &'a mut T) {
    println!("{:?}", parameter);
}

fn main(){
    let mut name : String = "random".to_string();
    random_func(&mut name);
    println!("{:?}", "compiled successfully");
}
```

error:

```
life_time_trait.rs:3:27: 3:29 error: lifetime parameters must be declared prior to type parameters
life_time_trait.rs:3 fn random_func<T : Debug, 'a>(parameter : &'a mut T) {

                                           ^~
```

Comment: The answer will end up being "because that's what the compiler said". What more are you looking for? This question seems like it cannot be answered in a useful way. You could likewise ask "why do you have to put left parenthesis before right parenthesis" or "why do you put the variable name before the variable type". These types of questions are hard to provide objective answers.

Comment: @Shepmaster My point was, instead of giving compilation error shouldn't the compiler be smart enough that the precedence of lifetime parameter and type parameter for this particular problem doesn't matter and should simply compile the program without showing any error.

Comment: I'm not sure that I think that changes anything — "why can't the compiler be smart enough to do *X* for me" isn't much better of a question. We'll see if anyone is brave enough to answer! ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is *the* reason, but remember that type parameters can have lifetime bounds, but lifetime parameters can't have type bounds. So putting them first means you don't need to deal with non-forward declarations.

Personally, I think this rule makes things a bit easier to understand, and a bit easier to implement. Win-win!

Comment: Given that type can have bounds depending on other types... not really?

Comment: Lifetimes can have bounds depending on other lifetimes too.

Answer (score 2):

When designing a language, there are many more or less arbitrary decisions.

For example, why allow `mut` in front of a function argument name when it is not necessary to achieve the same functionality? Why requiring `let` to declare a variable when it could be disambiguated anyway?

In general, it boils down to convenience:

- either for the user, aka sugar
- or for the implementer

To go back to my examples above:

- `mut` is syntax sugar, avoiding a `let mut name = name;` inside the function
- `let` keeps the grammar LL(1), making it easier to develop alternative parsers (for use in text editors or IDE for examples)

In this precise case, I do not know the exact reason, but that is besides the point. There are countless such more or less arbitrary design decisions (especially in syntax), and such bike shedding has little value.

One could argue that it would be slightly easier on the *writer*, to which another would reply that accommodating the *reader* is more important and attempt to demonstrate that the current form is more readable... such arguments are generally endless with each party refusing to budge.

I personally welcome such a compiler restriction (and wish for `rustfmt`), that's less debate over trivia down the road.